# Usage of binarySearch inside a method

Tags: java, binary-search

it gives me error which is understandable becase the method `indexOf(key)` has an `int` return type. All the method does is if the `key` is found then replace its existing `value` with the given `value`. If the `key` is not present dd the key in sorted order into the listn of keys and add the value at the same locat

Comment: What is `keys`? If `indexOf` is always going to return an int, why use `K` instead of `int` to capture the return value?

Comment: wow, I don't follow what you want. But i suggest that you declare this `public class MyComparator<K> implements Comparator<K>` like this `public class MyComparator<? extends Comparable> implements Comparator<? extends Comparable>` because you must have something that extends `Comparable` to make your `Comparator` work

Answer (score 0):

To get the key you need to get index using binary search and then use that index to get the actual key:

```
public V put(K key, V value) 
 {
     int keyIndex = this.indexOf(key);
     K getKey = keys.get(keyIndex);
     for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++)
     {
         if(getKey == keys.get(i))
         {
             keys.set(i, (K) value);
         }
         else 
         {
             keys.add(getKey);
             vals.add(value);
         }
     } 
     return value;
 }
```

Comment: What is the point of doing a binary search, if you are going to do a complete linear scan of the keys anyway?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, what and where do you mean I'm doing a linear scan of the keys?